# Wordpress :PHP sort items by randomness

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to php and wordpress.
(I have a python and ruby background though, I just don't know php)

And I have a page with items. Right now the last 20 items  are displayed on page (or something like this).  But I want to show not the last, but items in random order. 
This is code that lists items in archive.php file:

```
<?php echo category_description( get_category_by_slug('category-slug')->term_id ); ?></div>
<?php $col = 1;  $counter = 0;?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php ++$counter;?>
         .......
```

This code is not written by me. I clicked go to definition on have posts() function and got to this in wp-includes/class-wp.query.php

```
* @return bool True if posts are available, false if end of loop.
     */
    public function have_posts() {
        if ( $this->current_post + 1 < $this->post_count ) {
            return true;
        } elseif ( $this->current_post + 1 == $this->post_count && $this->post_count > 0 ) {
            /**
             * Fires once the loop has ended.
             *
             * @since 2.0.0
             *
             * @param WP_Query $this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
             */
            do_action_ref_array( 'loop_end', array( &$this ) );
            // Do some cleaning up after the loop
            $this->rewind_posts();
        } elseif ( 0 === $this->post_count ) {
            /**
             * Fires if no results are found in a post query.
             *
             * @since 4.9.0
             *
             * @param WP_Query $this The WP_Query instance.
             */
            do_action( 'loop_no_results', $this );
        }

        $this->in_the_loop = false;
        return false;
    }
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)
Here the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
    <?php 
        echo category_description( get_category_by_slug('category-slug')->term_id ); 
    ?>
    </div>
        <?php $col = 1;  $counter = 0;
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $subcategories = get_categories(array(
            'child_of'  => $categories[0]->cat_ID)
            );


        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby'   => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'category_name' => $subcategories[(count($subcategories) -1)]->slug 
            );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
         ++$counter;


        ?>
```

in tax_query elements of the array are optional

Comment: thanks for reply it works, but now it gives me items from another categories. What do I do to select items only from current category?

Comment: Well, what do I write instead of `slug in here`? The slug is not hardcoded it can be different at different categories?

Comment: from the code on your question it seems to be 'category-slug'

Comment: Now it shows me nothing found. May be I should not use category but taxonomy?

Comment: No help, still shows me items from another categories

Comment: what property value do you know for sure about the category you want to get?

Comment: I just have url like this: `http://mirspectechniki.ru/category/nasha-tehnika/ `or like this:                                                                                                         
                                             
               `http://mirspectechniki.ru/category/nasha-tehnika/ustanovki-dlya-bestranshejnoj-prokladki-i-zameny-kommunikatsij-gnb/ustanovki-neupravlyaemogo-prokola-grunta/`  And there is a category slug in this url, and I need to show items from this category

Comment: `nasha-tehnika` is the main category, it can have subcategories such  as 
 'ustanovki-dlya-bestranshejnoj-prokladki-i-zameny-kommunikatsij-gnb'  And this subcategory can also have subcategories, so I can't use 'nasha-technika' as slug everytime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172151/discussion-between-climon-and-user2950593).